# Parsing timestamp with value and plot by gnuplot

Tags: format, timestamp, gnuplot

I have these data.txt:

```
[1384395497218,679],[1384399097218,679],[1384402697218,679]...

[timestamp,value]
```

Where first is timestamp 1384395497218 -> 1384395497.218 -> Thu, 14 Nov 2013 02:18:17 GMT.
The second is count of something

I would like to plot lines graph with dates on the x-axis and count on the y-axis. How can I do this?

```
Example:
x-axis = "14 November" y-axis = "679"..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a quite strange input format. If you can, you should choose one which is better suited. Gnuplot cannot handle this, you must preprocess your data file before plotting it. That can be done e.g. with `perl` and regular expressions as follows:

If you have a data file `test.txt` with the values

```
[1384395497218,679],[1384399097218,679],[1384402697218,679]
```

and use the following call on the command line:

```
perl -pe 's/\[(\d+)([\d]{3}),(\d+)\],?/\1.\2 \3\n/g' test.txt
```

you get your data formatted as

```
1384395497.218 679
1384399097.218 679
1384402697.218 679
```

which can be plotted with gnuplot. To have the preprocessing done on-the-fly, use the syntax

```
plot '< perl ...'
```

A short script for you data is e.g.:

```
set timefmt '%s'
set xdata time
set format x '%d %B'
set xtics 24*60*60
getdata = '< perl -pe ''s/\[(\d+)([\d]{3}),(\d+)\],?/\1.\2 \3\n/g'' test.txt'
plot getdata using 1:2 with linespoints notitle
```

Some more notes:

- The time format `%s` reads in a timestamp, which can also have decimal digits (You could also drop them.
- `set xtics 24*60*60` sets one major tic at every day
- With `set format x '%d %B'` you can set a different format for the output formatting of the time on the x-axis.

Result with 4.6.4 is:

[image]